# Maven dependencies are failing but compiles anyway

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, nexus

I am compiling and running Java Spring software with a local nexus repository manager.
It works as proxy and correctly download and store any library.
**The build works** and the software is properly packaged but the Maven sync always shows an error:

```
Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.2.1 from/to localnexus (https://[localnexus]/repository/maven-public/): Transfer failed for https://[localnexus]/repository/maven-public/com/fasterxml/woodstox/woodstox-core/6.2.1/woodstox-core-6.2.1.jar
```

clicking on the link download the jar correctly.
The error also appears in the Maven dependency manager in intellij:

[image]

It's a bit annoying. What's wrong with my configs?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a network issue: `Transfer failed for ...`

Comment: yes but if i click on the link, the jar is downloaded correctly. 
And all other dep are downloaded.
That's the strangest part.

Comment: You might try to run maven with ```-X``` to see if that gives you any more info about why the transfere fails.

Comment: The download is then done via your browser not via Maven...there is a differences... You should check on plain command line... do you need proxy configurations/firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Same kind of issue I had faced with eclipse some time back. There might be Nexus SSL certificate issue which is creating the problem when connecting through your IDE. Generally what happens, we install certificate in our JRE(which is in our JDK). The problem  might be 1. you did not install the your Nexus Repo
server certificate. 2. You have installed cert but expired. 3. And this one is tricky and was the problem I faced -> On your machine there could be multiple JRE's installed. The problem of IDE is that when it tries to connect with our Nexus server, it picks the JRE(don't know on what criteria - May be the one one it finds first) which does not have the Nexus cert. The solution of it to install the Nexus Cert on all the JREs OR delete all except the one you are using(Obliviously your JDK). Try this may be this could also work for you.